# Checking returned data from php file with equal sign and get () method jquery

Tags: php, jquery, get

I have this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$.get('getturn.php', function(data){
    if (data!=='4') { alert ('  change'); }
    if (data=='4') { alert ('no change');}
    });
});
```

getturn.php echoes 4 if the turn is equal to a session id, and it echoes the turn number if otherwise. The getturn.php does as it should, it echoes 4 or a number like 0,1,2,3; however when I get the data like seen above from a different file, and check if it equals to 4, I can't get the correct answer... What am I doing wrong? I thought we could check if the output was yes with data=='yes' ? but we can't check numbers with data=='4'?

Comment: please paste your php code here too? also what happens if you do `console.log(data);` ?

Comment: Did you check the response via firebug. may be your ajax request is cached.

Comment: @GaryGreen data type is a string but when i make it `data='4'` and `data!='4'` it alerts both `change` and `no change`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you done an `alert(data);` to see what is returned?

I think you should try this slight modification:

```
if (data == '4') { alert ('no change');}
            else { alert ('  change'); }
```

Based on this answer: [How do the PHP equality (== double equals) and identity (=== triple equals) comparison operators differ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/80646/how-do-the-equality-double-equals-and-identity-triple-equals-compariso/80796#80796)

Comment: @Frosco hmm... for somereason localhost/getturn.php echoes `4` but when i alert it it alerts `1`. still the type is a string though..

Comment: @Logan the first part of your response cancels out the second part.  How are you sure that it echoed a 4?  Unless you're using your browser dev tools and inspecting the real response how can you know?

Comment: @Frosco well http://localhost/getturn.php returns only number `4` and nothing else... isn't that enough for checking the php file? Why should it be different when I use ajax get? Could you enlighten me please?

Comment: @Logan I don't know how else to explain, if alert(data) shows you `1` what does that tell you?

Comment: nevermind i found the problem in the php script; after it alerted `4` i did as in your answer and it worked, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

if understand your problem correctly, this will help:

```
data = parseInt(data);
if (!isNaN(data)) {
  if (data != 4) { ... }
  if (data == 4) { ... }
}
```

just convert "data" variable to numeric value(e.g. integer in this case)